# How to store a Scanner input and have it correspond with an array? Then pick a random element from that array

Tags: java, arrays, random, methods, constructor

Working on a beginner java project.

The idea of the program is to take in user's favorite genre and return a random recommendation based on a top 10 (starting with 3 now) list of books in each genre.

My main question is how could I take in their input, make it correspond to the right array and print out a random element from that array in the getRecommendation() method.

Code below (left out imports and public class):

```
public WhatBook() {
    
    System.out.println("Hello, what genre of book are you in the mood for?");
        System.out.println("Please enter: \n1 for Horror\n2 for Adventure\n3 for Crime\n4 for War\n5 for Scifi");
        while (true) {
        Scanner scanGenre = new Scanner(System.in);
        int bookGenre = scanGenre.nextInt();
        
        if (bookGenre < 1 || bookGenre > 5) {
            System.out.println("Please choose from the genres from 1 to 5.");
        } else {
            System.out.println(bookGenre + "? Great choice! Let's get some recommendations for you.");
            break;
        }
        
    }


public static String getRecommendation() {

    // pick random element of the entered genre array
    // create random object
    int rnd = new Random().nextInt(array.length);
    return array(rnd);

}

// public arrays
String[] horror = { "The Shining", "The Stand", "The Haunting of Hill House" };
String[] adventure = { "Into Thin Air", "Hatchet", "The Call of the Wild" };
String[] crime = { "In Cold Blood", "Devil in the White City", "Helter Skelter" };
String[] war = { "The Things They Carried", "All Quiet on the Western Front", "Catch-22" };
String[] scifi = { "Dune", "1984", "Ender's Game" };

public static void main(String[] args) {

    WhatBook user1 = new WhatBook();

}
```

I tried using a switch loop in the constructor to set each int value to its corresponding array. Like:

switch (bookGenre) {

case 1:
bookGenre = horror[0];
break;
etc...

but this doesn't work.

Any ideas how to store the bookGenre int value to match its array?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would make an Array or Arrays (a 2D array), from your existing book arrays:

```
String[][] genres = { horror, adventure, crime, war, scifi };
```

Just make sure that they are listed in the same order as your menu system.  Since your menu starts at 1, we'll have to subtract 1 from the user choice to make zero based like the array.

Next, I would change your `getRecommendation()` method to receive an array.  Additionally, I would declare a static instance of `Random` that can be re-used over and over, instead of creating a new one each time:

```
private static Random R = new Random();

public static String getRecommendation(String[] array) {
    // pick random element of the entered genre array
    // create random object
    int rnd = R.nextInt(array.length);
    return array[rnd];
}
```

Lastly, just make sure that the number the user entered is within the bounds of your array, and pass the corresponding array to the method:

```
int bookGenre = scanGenre.nextInt();
if (bookGenre >=1 && bookGenre <= genres.length) { // between 1 and genres.length to match the displayed menu
  System.out.println(bookGenre + "? Great choice! Let's get some recommendations.");
  String book = getRecommendation(genres[bookGenre - 1]); // subtract 1 to make it zero based
  System.out.println("Your recommendation: " + book);
}
else
{
  System.out.println("Invalid Choice.");
}
```

Here's the whole thing put together:

```
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Scanner;
public class WhatBook {

  private static Random R = new Random();

  // public arrays
  String[] horror = { "The Shining", "The Stand", "The Haunting of Hill House" };
  String[] adventure = { "Into Thin Air", "Hatchet", "The Call of the Wild" };
  String[] crime = { "In Cold Blood", "Devil in the White City", "Helter Skelter" };
  String[] war = { "The Things They Carried", "All Quiet on the Western Front", "Catch-22" };
  String[] scifi = { "Dune", "1984", "Ender's Game" };
  
  String[][] genres = { horror, adventure, crime, war, scifi };

  public WhatBook() {
      System.out.println("Hello, what genre of book are you in the mood for?");
      System.out.println("Please enter: \n1 for Horror\n2 for Adventure\n3 for Crime\n4 for War\n5 for Scifi\n");
      Scanner scanGenre = new Scanner(System.in);
      System.out.print("Your choice: ");
      int bookGenre = scanGenre.nextInt();
      if (bookGenre >=1 && bookGenre <= genres.length) {
        System.out.println(bookGenre + "? Great choice! Let's get some recommendations.");
        String book = getRecommendation(genres[bookGenre - 1]);
        System.out.println("Your recommendation: " + book);
      }
      else
      {
        System.out.println("Invalid Choice.");
      }
  }

  public static String getRecommendation(String[] array) {
      // pick random element of the entered genre array
      // create random object
      int rnd = R.nextInt(array.length);
      return array[rnd];
  }

}
```

Comment: A more advanced solution would use a [Map](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html) with the genre as the key, and the String array as the value.

Answer (score 0):

you're looking for the concept of [a field](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java/fields.html).

Comment: Okay, thanks. Will try to think over what the answer could be.

Comment: If I make bookGenre a public field am I heading in the right direction? So the getRecommendation() method can access it?